# Delphi load from database wrong in windows 7

Tags: delphi, unicode, fonts

I have a program write using Delphi 5 and we run it in our office on windows xp without problem, program has a MS ACCESS database and some forms load from database and save back.

when we run program in windows 7 the Arabic string load like this ?????? from database and error message hardcoded in program with this language too.

so what's your suggestion for solving this problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion is to understand clearly how the data is held in the database and how you are accessing it. You'll want to be clear on the encoding used in the database, the transmission between db and app, and how you handle the text in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using non-Unicode application, it is important to set the correct locale in Windows.

On the computer with Windows XP (on which everything is OK) go to "**Regional and Language Options**", select "**Advanced**" tab and note which language is selected in "**Language for non-Unicode programs**" group.

Now, set this language on the Windows 7 computer. Note that you will have to restart the computer in order to make this work.